# jQuery parent.sibling logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, parent, siblings

I am trying to click on an item, and have that item jump to the next column. as of now, when I click on the item, the item spills, to every other column.

Here is the code.

I am trying to only have the item move to the next column, and then to the following column.

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
 $('#groupOne').on('click', '.item', clickHolder);
 $('#groupOne').on('click', '.item', clickCup);
}

function clickHolder(event){
 $('.selected').appendTo($(this));
 $('.selected').removeClass('.selected');
}

function clickCup(){
 var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('.selected'); 
 var $sibling = $this.parents().siblings();
 var $detached = $this.detach(); 
  $sibling.append($detached); 
}
```

```html
 <div class="topRow">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
  <button>Add</button>
 </div>
 <table id="groupOne">
  <tr>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Banana</td>
   <td>14.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Apple</td>
   <td>5.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Tomato</td>
   <td>8.99</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <table id="groupTwo"></table>
 <table id="groupThree"></table>
 <table id=id="groupFour"></table>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: what exacly do you want to do?

Comment: you are bidding 2 events to the same dom object

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this. Not exactly sure what you want, but this might be a lead?

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).parents("table").append($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topRow">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
  <button>Add</button>
</div>
<table id="groupOne">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>14.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>5.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td>8.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="groupTwo"></table>
<table id="groupThree"></table>
<table id="groupFour"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to move up/down the item row `onclick` of it.

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
  $('#groupOne').on('click', '.item', clickCup);
}

function clickCup(){
  // Use this to move the row down 
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
  
  // Use this to move the row down 
  //$(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
  
}
```

```html
<div class="topRow">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
  <button>Add</button>
 </div>
 <table id="groupOne">
      <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Banana</td>
   <td>14.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Apple</td>
   <td>5.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Tomato</td>
   <td>8.99</td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <table id="groupTwo"></table>
 <table id="groupThree"></table>
 <table id=id="groupFour"></table>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
```